# Changing directory name to "gsoc" gives 404 error on website hosting

Tags: http-status-code-404, github-pages, hugo

**The problem**
Website https://tardis-sn.github.io/ has a section in navigation bar named GSoC. The relevent markdown files, if kept inside a folder named 'gsoc' the website gives 404 error while trying to access any of the pages after hosting on github pages.
But any other name of folder doesn't create that issue. Aditionally this issue doesn't occur on forks and on local system.

For every markdown file there exists an html file in gh-pages branch which can be accessed even if url is not mentioned in config.yaml but if that html file is present in a folder named gsoc that becomes inaccessable

**To Reproduce**

- Clone the master branch or fork it and clone it and then navigate to the clone via terminal
- Go into clone then content. Change the name of the folder 'gsoc' and in config.yaml file present inside clone directory replace the directory name likewise
- Run "hugo server" and click on the localhost link. Everything in the website works
- After making a push/merge with upstream master the website's gsoc pages will work perfectly unless you kept directory name as gsoc

I tried creating separate branches and renamed folder, config files,folders present in gh pages repository but it doesn't help